# How can I get Farsi/Arabic text to render correctly in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, arabic

I downloaded a number of Farsi fonts and they render individual characters fine but but don't join multiple characters together at all. Does anyone know how to get whole words to appear correctly? If someone knows how to do this in Arabic but not Farsi, that would help me get closer.

For instance: ك ا  should make كا

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To enable Farsi or Arabic in Photoshop CC, go to preferences (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) >  '**Type**' tab, then set the text engine to MIDDLE EASTERN AND SOUTH ASIAN.

Now restart Photoshop. From the menu choose **Type** > **language options** > select MIDDLE EASTERN FEATURES.

The latter enables the right-to-left direction in the paragraph panel.

Comment: I do this but dont work for me. Then i reset preferences and try again that solved.

Answer (score 2):

There was a plugin, years ago, called Parian that claimed to render Farsi text correctly. From what I can tell, it hasn't been updated in a very long time and there's not much chance it would work in any version later than Photoshop 7. I don't know of one that's current.

On the brighter side, there should be OpenType fonts able to form words correctly in Photoshop CS6 or later, with the expanded support for OpenType features. My own solution in a situation like this would be to shift over to InDesign, which has extensive support for position-sensitive alphabets, do the typography there, and copy/paste back into Photoshop. Illustrator may also support that feature, but InDesign is king of typesetting. In either case, you do have to start with an OpenType font that has the capability built in.

Longer term, you might visit the [Adobe wishform page](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform) and request that as a feature. Lobbying for features does work.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmpZiXReb_k
It has worked for me.

Photoshop provided support for right to left reading order text in previous versions with the "Middle Eastern", or "ME" Editions. That functionality is no longer native to Photoshop as of version CS5. The options are to purchase additional software, or trick Photoshop into formatting text properly by using a text box template made specifically to do it. In this tutorial, we use the following template: Go to: sites.google.com/site/arabicfarsiphotoshop/files Or: brainchamber.com/yourls search for ArabicFarsiPSD And download the template

Its a zip file. Extract it. And double click to open it in Photoshop. Photoshop ask you a question you can choose NO or Update. Use NO option. You dont wanna update. Now you can write from right to left in this template. Keep the orginal layer and duplicate template layer (Right click on layer and select douplicate layer option) and try to modify it as you desire. Save this template and everytime you need something new. you can open this file and duplicate the original layer and work on copy layer.

By the way you need to choose one of the Arabic font which is available as standard in photoshop to be able write in Persian. If you dont like standard Arabic fonts from Photoshop then search by google and install your favorite Persian font and install it. I personally prefer to go to behnevis.com and write my text in Latin and this site wil give you the Latin text in Persian. Copy the text from this site and paste it on your Photoshop right to left template. Enjoy!

Comment: Hi Arash! Welcome to GD.SE :) Any chance you can add information from the video to your answer? Videos can go down, so we try to keep the answers valid by themselves. Link-only ones are generally discouraged.

Comment: Sure Yisela. Here it comes:

Comment: Awesome! I edited the comments into your answer (you can edit it yourself too, just click on "Edit")

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable *Middle Eastern and South Asian* from *Edit → Preferences → Type.*
2. Close and restart Photoshop.
3. Use correct Arabic or Persian (Farsi) fonts. Some of those font don’t work correctly. One of best Persian (Farsi) fonts is [Shabnam](https://github.com/rastikerdar/shabnam-font).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> > Type > Choose Mid-east languages > "restart software"

Then in the main window of Photoshop over the ribbon go to Filters" > language options > Farsi digits

Comment: Welcome! Please do not only post an menu line, explain what it does step for step!